# Concatenating a dynamic number of fields (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

There's a table in our ERP system that tracks customer complaints.  The system assigns a complaint number to each complaint, and a service rep enters details of the complaint into a text box.  Due to ERP limitations, the complaint text can only be extracted in 125-character chunks into MySQL.

In the extracted table, each complaint has multiple lines, and there's a sequence field that tells you the order of the texts for the full complaint.  For any given complaint number, I need to select the full text of the complaint.  The number of text chunks for a complaint can vary significantly.  For each complaint, I would at least have the ability to select the max sequence number upfront to know how many chunks there are to piece together.

What's the most efficient way I could do this?  I know I could loop through the text chunks for each complaint and build up the full text of the complaint through a variable, but there are around 4,800 complaints which are comprised of around 39,000 text chunks, so I was hoping there may be a faster way.

To illustrate, the sequence numbers and text chunks may look something like this in the table:

1  --  The customer
2  --  is not happy
3  --  that their shipment
4  --  was late.

For this complaint, I want to capture "The customer is not happy that their shipment was late." in a text field.

Comment: Look at [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.